# Create DB link to oracle cloud database which installed in private network

Tags: oracle, ssh, ssh-tunnel, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have public IP, the Oracle cloud DB installed in private IP. through  the public IP we can establish ssh tunnel to private IP and forward localhost port to access Oracle cloud DB.

My task is to create DB link from my localhost oracle DB to cloud Oracle DB. So I can access Oracle cloud DB schema from my localhost oracle DB.

I using Putty to establish SSH & localhost port forward and I can access Oracle Cloud DB using SQL developer/Toad. So public/private IP and SSH details are correct.

In this case, how to create DB link?

Answer (score 0):

You already have forwarded connections coming to `localhost` port `X` to the target private IP in AWS (let it be RDS:1521). So your config is `localhost:X -> RDS:1521`. You also need schema name (`myusername`) and its password (`mypassword`).

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK mylink 
    CONNECT TO myusername IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=X))
           (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)
           (SERVICE_NAME=myrdsservicename)))';
```

Oracle's 12c syntax for creating db links [can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205).

Instead of using RAW connection parameters (as above) you my prefer to create an entry in `tnsnames.ora` for the connection string above and use the symbolic name for the localhost forwarded connection.

Comment: I have tried below syntax, CREATE DATABASE LINK mylink 
    CONNECT TO myusername IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=X))
           (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)
           (SERVICE_NAME=myrdsservicename)))';

Comment: I have tried below syntax, CREATE DATABASE LINK mylink 
    CONNECT TO myusername IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
    USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=X))
           (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)
           (SERVICE_NAME=myrdsservicename)))'; I given local forwarded port and service name, but i got error as ORA-12541 “TNS no listener.” I have used same port and service in toad/sql developer, it got connected.  But while trying through DB link it throw no listener error.